# evento keyPress tecla control && tecla +

Tags: c#, windows-forms, keypressevent

Buenas alguien sabe como se podría utilizar la combinación de las teclas ctrl y + desde el evento keypress o cualquier otro evento key? Gracias. He probado algo así pero no me funciona:

```
if(e.KeyChar ==Convert.ToChar(Keys.Control) && e.KeyChar =='+')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El keyChar para el '+' es 'add' el keyCode '107' proba tu código de la siguiente forma

```
$('#key').keypress(function (event) { var keycode = event.which; if (keycode == 107)});
```

Te paso un link con la [lista](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) de codigos